# Animação de elemento em CSS puro

Tags: css

Como eu posso realizar um esquema em puro CSS com uma bolinha simulando o tráfego, a bolinha ficaria circulando nas linhas, veja um esquema

```
SERVER --------> YOU
/\                |
|                 |
|                 *
|____  ME <_______|
```

Ficou meio estranho mas as é a demonstração da ideia, a bolinha, representada por `*`, ficaria andando nas linhas indo do SERVER->YOU->ME infinitamente, apenas para demonstrar

Pensei numa div com border e posicionar os 3 elementos com float mas ficaria gambiarra.. Como faze-lo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No exemplo abaixo usei `@keyframe` e `animation` do `CSS3` para modificar a posição do circulo conforme o progresso da animação. Para o posicionamento dos elementos usei `position:absolute` para posicioná-los de acordo com sua `div` pai.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid #3df;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 40%;
}
span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 10;
}
#server {
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
}
#you {
  top: -10px;
  right: -10px;
}
#me {
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 40%;
}
#bl {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  top: -7%;
  left: -5.5%;
  z-index: 11;
  -webkit-animation: ball 4s linear infinite;
  animation: ball 4s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes ball {
  0% {
    top: -7%;
    left: -5.5%;
  }
  25% {
    top: -7%;
    left: 96%;
  }
  50% {
    top: 94%;
    left: 96%;
  }
  75% {
    top: 94%;
    left: -5.5%;
  }
}
@keyframes ball {
  0% {
    top: -7%;
    left: -5.5%;
  }
  25% {
    top: -7%;
    left: 96%;
  }
  50% {
    top: 94%;
    left: 96%;
  }
  75% {
    top: 94%;
    left: -5.5%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <span id="you">YOU</span>
  <span id="server">SERVER</span>
  <span id="me">ME</span>
  <span id="bl"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Agradeço e muito pelo seu tempo gasto com meu problema!!!

Comment: Que isso, eu que agradeço por poder ajudar e com isso também aprender coisas novas.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode utilizar as coordenadas da página para posicionar os elementos 'server', 'you' e 'me' e utilizar a propriedade 'animation' para mover a bola. Tipo assim:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_animation_direction

e você pode fazer a bola com CSS desta forma:

```
.ball{
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: #000;
}
```